# Pass anchor tag IDs to AJAX calls

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My program is to display if there is an event on a specific date in a calendar. I go to my database to check if a date is with an event and echoes it to the user.

I have a loop that will generate multiple values, the ID will end up as their corresponding ID on the database.

Here is the tag that will have multiple IDs:

```
echo "<br /><a class='popper' id='$event_id' data-popbox='pop2' href='#'>See more...</a><br />";
```

how can I pass the IDs to this ajax call(my function is to hover for the link for the user to see a popbox with the details)?

```
$(function() {

 $( "#pop2" ).load( "GET.php", { eventid: <?php echo $event_id; ?> }, function() {});
var moveLeft = 0;
var moveDown = 0;

$('a.popper').hover(function(e) {
    var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        $(target).show();
        moveLeft = $(this).outerWidth();
        moveDown = ($(target).outerHeight() / 2);}, 

function() {
var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));

    $(target).hide();
        });

    $('a.popper').mousemove(function(thisEvent) {
        var target = '#' + ($(this).attr('data-popbox'));
        leftD = e.pageX + parseInt(moveLeft);
        maxRight = leftD + $(target).outerWidth();
        windowLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
        windowRight = 0;
        maxLeft = e.pageX - (parseInt(moveLeft) + $(target).outerWidth() + 20);
            if(maxRight > windowLeft && maxLeft > windowRight)
                {
                leftD = maxLeft;
                }
        topD = e.pageY - parseInt(moveDown);
        maxBottom = parseInt(e.pageY + parseInt(moveDown) + 20);
        windowBottom = parseInt(parseInt($(document).scrollTop()) + parseInt($(window).height()));
        maxTop = topD;
        windowTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());
            if(maxBottom > windowBottom){
                topD = windowBottom - $(target).outerHeight() - 20;
                } 
            else if(maxTop < windowTop){
                topD = windowTop + 20;
                }
        $(target).css('top', topD).css('left', leftD);
});
   });
```

My main problem is, only one value is being returned when I hover different links for events. How can I pass the specific ID of what the user hovered and query it in my PHP file.

Thanks in advance for answering! :)

Comment: I've done something similar with a calendar recently. Calendar pops up on the screen, a call to the db populates ALL of the elements using the jQuery .data() statement. Then when the user hovers, it just reads the assocated .data info and displays in in a div. No multiple calls to the db.

Comment: me too, that is what I've been stumped for days :( do you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

this is some mad spaghetti code. Try breaking down the problem into steps.

1) Does the php echo out the html correctly?

2) Can you select that element in the console?

```
$('.popper')
```

3) Does it have an id?

```
$('.popper').attr('id')
```

4) Can you log that element's id on a hover state?

```
$('.popper').bind('hover', function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

5) store it as a variable

```
$('.popper').bind('hover', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(id);
});
```

6) Call a function:

```
function getDetails(id){
  $.get('http://example.com/?details='+id, function(data){
      console.log(data);
  })
}

$('.popper').bind('hover', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   getDetails(id);
});
```

Comment: I don't know If I understand correctly but I need to put this

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

in my mousemove to get the ID? is that it?

Comment: Also, I want to get the data from the database and populate it in a class #pop2 because this will display a popupbox.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be relevant to you, but I'll post my code anyway. I have four months on a screen at the same time. When the user clicks on a specific date another popup of the daily schedule comes up in a jQuery dialog (e.g., 9:00 - name, comments, purpose of appointment, etc) This is general enough so that you could use it for specific time periods, days, months, whatever you want.

I don't use individual element identifiers, I use pseudo-class selectors.

The code below reads the db and populates each an every one of the time periods with the relevant data for that time period. So when you hover over the time period, all of the information stored pops up in another window.

```
 $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              data: {   date: scheduledate,
                     service: typeofservice},
               url: 'readdayschedulebackend.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          })
           .done(function(result){
                                  ttime = new Date();
                                  ttime.setHours(8,0);
                                  for(var t = 0; t <30; ++t)
                                    {
                                     tablehours = ttime.getHours();
                                     tableminutes = ttime.getMinutes();
                                     if (tablehours < 10)
                                       { tablehours = '0' + tablehours; }
                                     if (tableminutes < 10)
                                       { tableminutes = '0' + tableminutes; }
//                                     console.log(tablehours + ':' + tableminutes);
                                     $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(1)').html( tablehours + ':' + tableminutes );
                                     tablehours2 = ttime.getHours()+4;
                                       if (tablehours2 < 10)
                                         { tablehours2 = '0' + tablehours2; }
                                     $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(3)').html( tablehours2 + ':' + tableminutes );

                                     stringtime = tablehours + ':' + tableminutes + ':00';
                                     stringtime2 = tablehours2 + ':' + tableminutes + ':00';

                                     ttime = new Date(ttime.setMinutes( ttime.getMinutes() + 10 ));
                                     $.each( result, function(index, element){
                                        if (element.time == stringtime)
                                           { 
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').css( "background-color", "#F578A2" );
                                            tdname = element.lastname + ', ' + element.firstname + ' ' + element.middlename;
                                            tdname = tdname.substring(0,10);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').text( tdname );
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdlastname', element.lastname);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdfirstname', element.firstname);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdmiddlename', element.middlename);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tddob', element.dob);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdlocalid', element.localid);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tduniqueid', element.uniqueid);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdcomments', element.comments);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tddate', element.date);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdtime', element.time);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(2)').data( 'tdservice', element.service);
                                            }
                                        if (element.time == stringtime2)
                                           {
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').css( "background-color", "#F578A2" );
                                            tdname2 = element.lastname + ', ' + element.firstname + ' ' + element.middlename;
                                            tdname2 = tdname2.substring(0,10);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').text( tdname2 );
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdlastname', element.lastname);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdfirstname', element.firstname);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdmiddlename', element.middlename);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tddob', element.dob);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdlocalid', element.localid);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tduniqueid', element.uniqueid);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdcomments', element.comments);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tddate', element.date);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdtime', element.time);
                                            $('#popupscheduletable tbody tr:nth-child('+ (t+1) +') td:nth-child(4)').data( 'tdservice', element.service);

                                            }
                                        });
                                     }
              });//end ajax.done
});//end open large day dialog
```

---

//hover over scheduled time and show details
$('#popupscheduletable tbody tr td:nth-child(even)').hover(
                                                           function(){
                                                          if ( $(this).html().length > 1  ) 
                                                                        {
                                                                         $('.rolloverdiv').html( $(this).data('tdlastname') + ', ' + 
                                                                                   $(this).data('tdfirstname') + ' ' +
                                                                              $(this).data('tdmiddlename') + ' ' + '
' +
                                                                              'DOB: ' +
                                                                              $(this).data('tddob')+ '
' +
                                                                              $(this).data('tdcomments') + '
'
                                                                              );
                                                                         } else {
                                                                         $('.rolloverdiv').html( ' ' );
                                                                         }
                                                           },
                                                           function(){
                                                                      $('.rolloverdiv').html( ' ' )
                                                                      }
                                                           );

```
===========================================
//hover over scheduled time and show details
$('#popupscheduletable tbody tr td:nth-child(even)').hover(
                                                           function(){
                                                          if ( $(this).html().length > 1  ) 
                                                                        {
                                                                         $('.rolloverdiv').html( $(this).data('tdlastname') + ', ' + 
                                                                                   $(this).data('tdfirstname') + ' ' +
                                                                              $(this).data('tdmiddlename') + ' ' + '<br>' +
                                                                              'DOB: ' +
                                                                              $(this).data('tddob')+ '<br>' +
                                                                              $(this).data('tdcomments') + '<br>'
                                                                              );
                                                                         } else {
                                                                         $('.rolloverdiv').html( ' ' );
                                                                         }
                                                           },
                                                           function(){
                                                                      $('.rolloverdiv').html( ' ' )
                                                                      }
                                                           );
```

Comment: so whenever the user hovers to a specific time, you do an ajax call and pass a specific pseudoclass to determine the value on the database?